# loading glove word embedding has encoding error

Tags: python, encoding, word-embedding

I want to load pre-trained word embedding from glove, and there are some errors of encoding, I have tried encoding, but no work, how to fix this?

```
def load_word_embedding_glove(glovefile):
print ("loading golve word embddings...")
f = open(glovefile, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
model = {}
for line in f:
    splitLine = line.split()
    word = splitLine[0]
    embdding = [float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]]
    model[word] = embdding
print ("glove word embedding is loaded")
return model
```

I then print (model), the error occurs:

```
filepath = "../Pretrained/glove/glove.6B.100d.txt"
model = load_word_embedding_glove(filepath)
print (model)
```

the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 208465: ordinal not in range(128)
```

by the way, I used python 3.

Comment: I aslo tried, f = open(glovefile, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'), still the error

Comment: In which environment do you run the script?

Comment: python3, and I remove the encoding='utf-8', it's working, but I was wondering how to remove the words that contain non English letters.

Comment: I mean - do you run the program in Linux terminal, Windows cmd or some IDE?

Comment: I used Mac computer and sublimetext for coding

Comment: So you run it in Sublime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158216/discussion-between-maximtitarenko-and-hao-chen).